# Trying to find the mean while using multiple conditions without creating a baseline subsample but keep getting this error

Tags: r, economics

```
mean(pumf$AGEGRP[pumf$AGEGRP<88 & pumf$WAGES>10,000 & pumf$AGEGRP>8 & pumf$WAGES<400,000 & pumf$WRKACT<99 & pumf$ABOID==6])
```

> Error in pumf$AGEGRP[pumf$AGEGRP < 88 & pumf$WAGES > 10, 0 &
> pumf$AGEGRP >  :    incorrect number of dimensions

Answer (score 0):

Remove the commas in between numbers eg. `pumf$WAGES>10,000`, `pumf$WAGES<400,000` etc.
`pumf$WAGES>10,000` should be `pumf$WAGES>10000` and
`pumf$WAGES<400,000` should be `pumf$WAGES<400000`

A data.frame is a 2D object. The many commas make R assume that the object you're subsetting from has more than 2 dimensions.